# How to know if WMS GetLegendGraphic supports bounding box?

Tags: wms, extents, sld, getlegendgraphic

I am working on an application where users can input WMS layers, which is displayed on a map along with the respective legend graphic. Now, I want to display content specific legend graphics based on the bounding box of the map.

I construct the parameters for the GetLegendGraphic on the fly, based on the rules for the specific server the layer originates from. Typically the parameters needed for this are BBOX, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CRS/SRS, SRCWIDTH, SRCHEIGHT etc, but which parameters are mandatory, and the meaning of each parameter differ slightly from server to server, making it difficult to automate the process.

I have found documentation for GeoServer, MapServer and QGisServer on how to use GetLegendGraphic along with the specific bbox parameters, and most of the layers originating from these servers work well with bounding box legends.

My questions are:

- How can I tell from which server the layer originates from? Up until now, I have only "guessed" the server based on the WMS URL which often contain the name of the server e.g "GeoServer".
- How can I tell if a specific layer / WMS service supports content dependent GetLegendGraphic, which parameters to use and which rules to follow?
- Does ArcGIS support GetLegendGraphic with bounding box? If so, what are the rules to follow?
- Is GetLegendGraphic and bbox part of the OGC-standard?

I find it difficult to automatically show the content dependent legend graphic to the users, as there are so many different servers and services, each with their own implementations. I know also that some services don't support getlegendgraphic with bbox at all.

Comment: You can always add a BBOX, to any GetLegendGraphic request, if the server doesn't  understand the parameter it will ignore it.  If MapServer, GeoServer, QGISServer use different (vendor) BBOX formats you could add all of them.

Comment: @nmtoken The problem with this, is that some of the parameters, e.g. width and height, which are necessary parts of the bbox-parameters, have different meaning in e.g. MapServer and Geoserver. In some cases they are used for the width and height of the icons that appear in the legend graphic, while in other case, width and height specifies the width and height of the map image.

Comment: height and width have defined meanings in the SLD specification.  They are hints to size of the returned graphic (the image).  If software is using that incorrectly perhaps file a bug report

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetLegendGraphic is defined in the SLD standard https://www.ogc.org/standard/sld/. Support for SLD is optional in WMS.

I think that you have done almost everything that you can. WMS is based on the standard and the mark of the WMS server is not supposed to have any meaning for the users. Service admins rather try to hide the fingerprints that reveal the server software for security reasons.

The SLD standard defines only these parameters for GetLegendGraphic

> VERSION Required
>
> REQUEST Required
>
> LAYER Required
>
> STYLE Optional
>
> FEATURETYPE Optional
>
> RULE Optional
>
> SCALE Optional
>
> SLD Optional
>
> SLD_BODY Optional
>
> FORMAT Required
>
> WIDTH Optional
>
> HEIGHT Optional
>
> EXCEPTIONS Optional

Other parameters are allowed, but there are no rules about how the existence and usage of the additional parameters could be advertised in GetCapabilities.

> Vendor-specific parameters may be added to GetLegendGraphic requests